# variable undefined in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am trying to use the value of `currentUser` in the function inside of the `useEffect` Hook, but the value seems not to be the user's object, that I want it to be when using it. Here is the code:

```
function Chat() {   

    const currentUser = useAuth()

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchParticipants = async () => {
            console.log(currentUser.uid) // not defined
        }
        fetchParticipants()
    }, [])
}
```

That is the `useAuth()` function that is being called

```
export function useAuth() {
    const [ currentUser, setCurrentUser ] = useState();

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsub = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => setCurrentUser(user));
        return unsub;
    }, [])

    return currentUser;
}
```

Comment: Put your function DEFINITION outside of the useEffect + if the function is async, then you should await for it.

Comment: @AmirH.Bagheri — Putting it outside `useEffect` will cause it to run on every render, which is undesirable.

Comment: state updates may be [asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Comment: @AmirH.Bagheri — `await` is only useful if you want to wait for a promise to resolve before continuing. There's nothing after `fetchParticipants()` in the function, so that would be pointless. The function doesn't do anything asynchronous so the use of the `async` keyword is pointless too.

Comment: I mean this:
 const fetchParticipants = async () => {
            console.log(currentUser.uid) // not defined
        }
useEffect(() => {
       
        fetchParticipants()
    }, [])

Comment: @AmirH.Bagheri — If you do that then `fetchParticipants` is defined outside the effect, so it should be added to the dependency array for the effect so the effect re-runs every time it changes, so the effect now runs on every render, which is undesirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initial value of `currentUser` is going to be `undefined` because that is what you (don't) pass to the state when you set it up in your hook.

So the effect is first going to run with `undefined` as the value of `currentUser`.

Later, the `onAuthStateChanged` will trigger and update the state.

This will trigger a re-render and `currentUser` will be the value you want.

**However**, your effect will **not** re-run because the dependency array is `[]`. You need to tell it to re-run the function when the value updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchParticipants = async () => {
        console.log(currentUser.uid) // not defined
    }
    fetchParticipants()
}, [currentUser]) // <-------------------- Dependancy array
```